# Changing JENKINS_HOME in /etc/sysconfig/jenkins not working

Tags: jenkins, systemd, rhel

So I wanted to change the default JENKINS_HOME location. I pretty much always found the "edit the jenkins configuration" solution so I did that. I followed this guide https://phoenixnap.com/kb/change-jenkins-home-directory

Seemed legit, but it didn't work. /var/lib/jenkins is still JENKINS_HOME. I also tried setting a env var but that too did not work...

Does anyone have any clues as to why the configuration at /etc/sysconfig/jenkins is not being read/loaded?

Comment: I installed Jenkins from RPM. Installing on RHEL8.

Comment: Then it's using ,,`systems`. Read the [installation instructions](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/systemd-services/#managing-systemd-services) for [systemd](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/360052728092-How-can-I-install-Jenkins-as-a-systemd-service)

Comment: For anyone else landing here, [Phoenixnap.com instructions for Linux](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/change-jenkins-home-directory#change-jenkins-home-on-linux) are obsolete, post [jenkins-2.332.1](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.332/#linux-installation-packages-use-systemd). See systemd [blog post](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2022/03/25/systemd-migration/) and [service management instructions](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/systemd-services/). See also [How do I override or configure systemd services?](https://askubuntu.com/a/659268)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Ian W. This is a system bug that requires modification of the startup script.

```
vim /usr/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service
```

[image: jenkins.service]

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart jenkins.service
```

[Managing systemd services](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/systemd-services/#managing-systemd-services)

Comment: Did you [raise an issue](https://issues.jenkins.io/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20JENKINS%20) on this

Comment: Why did you `vim` instead of `systemctl edit jenkins` per [instructions](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/systemd-services/#overriding-service-configurations). Modifying using `systemctl edit jenkins` worked for me.